# how to update log4j on zookeeper instance

Tags: log4j, apache-zookeeper

we try to update log4j on one instance

i copied some file and removed old files. after that zookeeper not running

I copied these files

```
cp log4j-api-2.20.0.jar
cp log4j-core-2.20.0.jar
cp log4j-slf4j-impl-2.20.0.jar
```

I removed these file

```
rm -f log4j-1.2.16.jar
rm -f slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
```

Comment: Did it crash with any logs? Or not because you changed the logging library that controls how errors are reported?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. The source code is pre-compiled with a specific set of dependencies.

I suggest looking through Zookeeper JIRA to see if/when they plan to upgrade to log4j2. In the meantime, they may have already migrated to reload4j, which addresses several CVE of log4j 1.x, and if so, you should upgrade all of Zookeeper to that version, not cherry pick and add certain files that aren't used by the server's source code